# Installing kunstmaan/adminlist-bundle with Symfony 2.8 or 3.1

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php, kunstmaan

I have a Symfony 3.1 project which uses the finder component. I'm now trying to build a CRUD interface with kunstmaan/adminlist-bundle.

I'm struggling to resolve requirements for composer.

From starting installing kunstmaan bundles it appears they are only compatible with Symfony 2.7 or 2.8?

I seem to have been going in circles with this for a while. What is a good strategy to resolve these issues?

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "jochen/processor",
    "license": "proprietary",
    "type": "project",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "": "src/"
        },
        "classmap": [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Tests\\": "tests/"
        }
    },
    "require": {
        "php": ">=7.0.0",
        "symfony/symfony": "2.7.*",
        "doctrine/orm": "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle": "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle": "^2.7",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu": "^1.0",
        "symfony/finder": "@dev",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle": "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "^2.0",
        "kunstmaan/admin-bundle": "@dev",
        "kunstmaan/adminlist-bundle": "@dev",
        "kunstmaan/generator-bundle": "^3.5"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "sensio/generator-bundle": "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge": "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "symfony-scripts": [
            "Incenteev\\ParameterHandler\\ScriptHandler::buildParameters",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::buildBootstrap",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::clearCache",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installAssets",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::installRequirementsFile",
            "Sensio\\Bundle\\DistributionBundle\\Composer\\ScriptHandler::prepareDeploymentTarget"
        ],
        "post-install-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd": [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "extra": {
        "symfony-app-dir": "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir": "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir": "var",
        "symfony-web-dir": "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir": "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install": "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters": {
            "file": "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

Composer output

```
composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - kunstmaan/generator-bundle 3.5.x-dev requires symfony/symfony ~2.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev].
    - kunstmaan/generator-bundle 3.5.0 requires symfony/symfony ~2.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev].
    - kunstmaan/generator-bundle 3.5.1 requires symfony/symfony ~2.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev].
    - kunstmaan/generator-bundle 3.5.x-dev requires symfony/symfony ~2.8 -> satisfiable by symfony/symfony[2.8.x-dev].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony 2.8.x-dev
    - Installation request for kunstmaan/generator-bundle ^3.5 -> satisfiable by kunstmaan/generator-bundle[3.5.0, 3.5.1, 3.5.x-dev].
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The kunstmaan/generator-bundle "^3.5" that you have in your composer.json requires symfony 2.8 (as you can see in https://packagist.org/packages/kunstmaan/generator-bundle#3.5.1). In your composer.json you have symfony 2.7.*. Change it to 2.8.*.